# Display all rows in table even when WHERE statement does not match

Tags: mysql

I have a table delarations where users can record the time they spent on projects. Declarations have a begin and end time.

I want for a specific project (id = 1), a grand total of seconds that every user has spent on the project, **even if a user didn't spent any time on the project at all**.

Tables (simplified):

```
users
-----
- id
- name
- ...

projects
--------
- id
- name

declarations
------------
- id
- user_id
- project_id
- begin
- end
```

Let's say there are 2 users. User ID=1 has spent some time on projects, and user ID=2 didn't do anything.

```
select   users.*, sum(timestampdiff(second, declarations.start, declarations.end)) as seconds
from     users
join     declarations on declarations.user_id = users.id
where    declarations.project_id = 1
group by users.id
```

With the above query, only user 1 will appear. How can I modify the query in such way to include all the other users as well, with a value of `0` for `seconds`?

Comment: hmm, how about removing the where condition?

Comment: @TuanAnhTran Then all the projects will appear, I want only a specific project. Problem persist, if user 2 didn't contribute to any project.

Comment: my bad. didn't read the question carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and move that `WHERE` condition to `JOIN ON` condition like

```
select users.*, 
sum(timestampdiff(second, declarations.start, declarations.end)) as seconds
from users 
left join declarations on declarations.user_id = users.id
and declarations.project_id = 1
group by users.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this solution has the same problem as the suggestion of @TuanAnhTran in the comments section

Comment: @Thijs, shouldn't be. Notice that, I have used a left join instead of inner join which will get all users.

Comment: Ah great, I read over the additional project_id = 1 limitation the join. Thanks, works :) So simple in fact, but I simply didn't see it